# ckeditor_uploader stop working after deploy static files in google cloud storage

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

i work on a django app and right after i deploy the static files on google clouds the ckeditor and ckeditor_uploader stop working but every other static is working perfectly

ckeditor settings :

```
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'width': 'auto',
        'toolbar': None,
    },
    'simple': {
            'width': 'auto',
            'toolbar': [
                ['Undo','Redo','Find','Replace'],
                ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strikethrough','Subscript','Superscript'],
                ['Link','Unlink'],
                ['Blockquote','TextColor'],
                ['Format','Font','Size'],
                ['Maximize']
            ],


        },

}
```

static and media and google cloud settings :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/media/")
'''
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
'''



# CONFIG
# Google BUCKETS CONFIG
# google credential
from google.oauth2 import  service_account
GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'googlekey.json')
)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
GS_BUCKET_NAME = '*****'
GS_PROJECT_ID = '******'
GS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
GS_FILE_OVERWRITE  = False
GS_LOCATION = ''

#MEDIA_URL = f'https://storage.googleapis.com/{GS_BUCKET_NAME}/'
```

i ran 'python manage.py collectstatic' to upload all the files to google cloud

if i remove google settings ckeditor run again

[without google settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI1tz.png)

[with google settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6bzt.png)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem while working and the simple solution to your question is:

Add this in your `settings.py` file:

`CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/'`

You can read this for more info: https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#required